# post-commit hook timeout

Tags: svn, jenkins, post-commit, svn-hooks

I have written a post-commit hook just like as its shown in  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin to trigger a Jenkins build if someone commits something to subversion.

Recently, one of our authentication servers for Jenkins went down. My post-commit hook does not timeout in 2 secs. It waits and waits. How do I set a timeout for this in my post-commit hook?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what step failed for you. I'm assuming the POST to Jenkins failed (and not the svnlook to get the changes) and I'm assuming you're using `wget` as in the Jenkins example.

Instead of:

```
/usr/bin/wget \
    --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
    --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
    --output-document "-" \
    $JENKINS/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

you can set the timeout with `-T`:

```
/usr/bin/wget -T 2 \
    --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
    --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
    --output-document "-" \
    $JENKINS/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

Try `wget --help` if you need more options.